# ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Input, Add, BatchNormalization, Lambda, Concatenate, Reshape
from keras.models import Model
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import pandas as pd
import pydicom as dicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pydicom
import cv2
import os

def resize_dcm(dcmdosyası, boyut):
    dcmgörsel = pydicom.read_file(dcmdosyası)
    img = dcmgörsel.pixel_array
    img = cv2.resize(img, boyut, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    dcmgörsel.PixelData = img.tobytes()
    dcmgörsel.Rows, dcmgörsel.Columns = img.shape
    return dcmgörsel

folder = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/data/'

ana1 = [f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir()]

for ana2 in ana1:
    görseller = [f.path for f in os.scandir(ana2) if f.is_file()]

    for görsellercücük in görseller:
        resize2 = resize_dcm(görsellercücük, (800, 800))
        yeni = os.path.join(ana2, os.path.basename(görsellercücük))
        pydicom.write_file(yeni, resize2)

inputs = Input(shape=(800,800,1))
input2 = Input(shape=(1))
input3 = Input(shape=(1))

x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

res1 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
res2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(res1)
x = Add()([x, res2])

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

res1 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
res2 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(res1)
x = Add()([x, res2])

res1 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
res2 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(res1)
x = Add()([x, res2])

x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)

res1 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
res2 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(res1)
x = Add()([x, res2])

res1 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
res2 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(res1)
x = Add()([x, res2])

x = Flatten()(x)
x = Concatenate()([x,input2,input3])
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(4096, activation='relu')(x)
output = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x) #birads score
output2 = Dense(4, activation='softmax')(x) #kompozisyon

output3 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x) #bolge 1
output4 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x) #bolge 2
output5 = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x) #bolge 3


model = Model([inputs, input2,input3], [output,output2, output3])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/USER/Desktop/asdsadasdas.xlsx')
data.rename(columns={'HASTANO': 'ID', 'BIRADS KATEGORİSİ':'birads', 'MEME KOMPOZİSYONU': 'comp', 'KADRAN BİLGİSİ (SAĞ)': 'areaR', 'KADRAN BİLGİSİ (SOL)': 'areaL'}, inplace=True)
data.replace(['BI-RADS0', 'BI-RADS1-2', 'BI-RADS4-5'], [0,1,2], inplace=True)
data.drop(data.columns[5], inplace=True, axis=1)
data['comp'].value_counts()
data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

def transform_to_hu(medical_image, image):

    intercept = medical_image.RescaleIntercept

    slope = medical_image.RescaleSlope

    hu_image = image * slope + intercept

    return hu_image


def train():
    mainDir = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/data/'
    for d in data.iterrows():
        patientDir = mainDir + str(d[1][0])
        for f in os.listdir(patientDir):
            yon = 1 if f[0] == 'R' else 0
            view = 1 if f[1] == 'M' else 0
            dcm = dicom.dcmread(patientDir + '/' + f)
            image = transform_to_hu(dcm, dcm.pixel_array)
            o1 = 0
            o2 = 0
            o3 = 0
            areaStr = d[1]['area' + ('R' if yon == 1 else 'L')]
            if areaStr!= 0:
                areaStr = areaStr.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
                lst = areaStr.split(',')
                newLst = list(map(lambda x : x.replace('"', ''), lst))
                print(newLst)
                for a in newLst:
                    if(a == 'MERKEZ'):
                        o2 = 1
                        continue
                    t = a.split(' ')
                    if(view == 1): #mlo
                        if t[0] == 'ÜST':
                            o1 = 1
                        else:
                            o3 = 1
                    else:
                        if t[1] == 'DIŞ':
                            o1 = 1
                        else:
                            o3 = 1
            print(o1, o2, o3, sep=', ')
            model.fit([image, yon, view], [d[1]['birads'], d[1]['comp'], o1, o2, o3])
        break
train()



Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\aaac.py", line 157, in <module>
    train()
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\aaac.py", line 155, in train
    model.fit([image, yon, view], [d[1]['birads'], d[1]['comp'], o1, o2, o3])
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1081, in select_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>", "<class 'int'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>", "<class 'int'>"})

Process finished with exit code 1
```

```
hello i wrote a deep learning code. At first, I shaped the code in accordance with the resnet architecture, and then I tried to obtain an output by combining the data on excel and visual. I have encountered such an error, I do not know why.
```

![Topluluk Tarafından Doğrulandı simgesi](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)

Comment: Is there any error ? Please do not post images.

Comment: yes, ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'numpy.ndarray'>", "<class 'int'>"}), (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'str'>", "<class 'int'>"})